# Concatenate string combinations in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a lot of (tailwind) color strings, which I would like to restrict my type system to. For demo purposes I just display 3*3 here:

```
text-red-500    text-red-700    text-red-900
text-amber-500  text-amber-700  text-amber-900
text-yellow-500 text-yellow-700 text-yellow-900
```

I would like to do something like:

```js
type Color = "red" | "amber" | "yellow"
type Tint = "500" | "700" | "900"
type TailwindColor = "text-" + Color + "-" + Tint
```

Is there a way for me to do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template string types:

```
type Color = "red" | "amber" | "yellow"
type Tint = "500" | "700" | "900"
type TailwindColor = `text-${Color}-${Tint}`
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQPYBskCc4F44CJ0wAmucAPngIYC2ARjOiebhDCmgO66iSxwAqASwB2YbHgCsABkmM8AdmmzcATkXdo8PhQEp2wwsjSYcAAzAwAHmAC0AEgDehjAF879wSOcmgA)

You should take care though such combinatorial unions will tend to slow down the compiler if they get to large, and there are limits to the maximum size of a union that TypeScript will allow (not sure what it is, but there is a hard limit, [ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=114&pln=4&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQPYBskCc4F44CJ0wAmucAPngIYC2ARjOiebhDCmgO66iSxwAqASwB2YbHgCsABkmM8AdmmzcATkXdo8PhQEp2wwsjSYcAAzAwAHmAC0AEgDehjAF879wSNcOn6L++Fgfj5+HoFuwW6hQagu4TG+JkA))